# Prove there is no closed-form solution to equations with e^x and x

Tags: closed-form

I have the equation

$$\frac{b}{x}+\frac{ae^x}{1-e^x}=0$$

How do I prove this equation has no closed-form solution for $x$?

Edit: please note $a,b>0$

Comment: Simplifies to $e^{-x}+\frac{a}{b}x-1=0$; therefore are you assuming that $\frac{a}{b}$ be  a non-zero constant?

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have mentioned, $a,b>0$

Comment: Mobeus Zoom, does your post then actually not explicitly and directly say that $\frac a b$ is a non-zero constant and hence $b=ka$ in answer below is actually relying on deduction made explicitly so far only in @JamesArathoon's comment?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you mean *no closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions*.

Let $b=k a$ which makes the equation to be
$$k+(x-k)e^x=0$$ Now, let $x=k+y$  to make $$y e^{k+y}+k=0 \implies y e^y=-ke^{-k}$$ and the solution is 
$$y=W_{-1}\left(-ke^{-k} \right)$$ where appears the lower branch of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). In the real domain, this function is defined for $0 < k \leq 1$.

Back to $(x,a,b)$ this gives
$$x=\frac{b}{a}+W_{-1}\left(-\frac{b }{a}e^{-\frac{b}{a}}\right)$$

Comment: So how do you show there is no closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: @JairTaylor. This is the big question, I fully agree ! Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I guess one could go from here and bring in the proof that Lambert W doesn't have a closed-form solution in elementary functions, even though this may not be a proof of the overall lemma.

Comment: The other thing I'm wondering is, what if $b>a$ (so that $b/a<1$ is not true and the Lambert W isn't defined for our domain)?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for solutions in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

$$\frac{b}{x}+\frac{ae^x}{1-e^x}=0$$
$$axe^x-be^x+b=0\tag{1}$$

The left-hand side of equation (1) is an expression of both $x$ and $e^x$, algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$. It can be shown that such expressions don't have elementary inverses:
[How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse)

For $a,b\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, equation (1) is an algebraic equation of both $x$ and $e^x$. Lin (1983) proved, assuming Schanuel's conjecture ist true, that such equations, if irreducible, don't have solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).